# Is bleaching powder same as Sodium Hypochlorite?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

i want to know is Sodium Hypochlorite is same as bleaching powder.
can some one please let me know.

Comment: The main ingredient in any bleach is **hypochlorite**. So, [sodium hypochlorite](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110360/is-sodium-hypochlorite-100-concentrate-possible), [potassium hypochlorite](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87596/why-dont-we-use-potassium-hypochlorite-for-bleach), [calcium hypochlorite](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33759/what-is-the-formula-of-bleaching-powder) all are bleach.

Comment: can e use bleaching powder for covid if not getting Sodium Hypochlorite ?

Comment: Please don't do anything like that..

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. Didn't you understand my comment above? Check the composition of your "bleaching powder". If it has hypochlorite, it can be used as bleach.

Comment: The hypochlorite is the bit with the bleaching power, the metal ion is not important

Answer (score 3):

Historically, ['Bleaching Powder'](https://books.google.com/books?id=JXZZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=Mellor+on+bleaching+powder&source=bl&ots=BNYg0jMXrO&sig=ACfU3U1RauOGi9_AwMGzoqMMPiLJkhzT5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ16vlpqLpAhWET98KHTJ1CNwQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Mellor%20on%20bleaching%20powder&f=false) has referred to Calcium hypochlorite, Ca(OCl)2. To quote [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleach):

> Bleaching powder (formerly known as "chlorinated lime"), usually a mixture of calcium hypochlorite (Ca(ClO)2), calcium hydroxide (lime, Ca(OH)2), and calcium chloride (CaCl2) in variable amounts.[16] Sold as a white powder or in tablets, is used in many of the same applications as sodium hypochlorite, but is more stable and contains more available chlorine.

It was prepared by the action of chlorine on moist lime, hence the products listed.

$\ce{Cl2 + H2O <=> H+ + Cl- + HOCl }$

$\ce{Ca(OH)2 + 2 HOCl <=> Ca(OCl)2 + 2 H2O }$

$\ce{Ca(OH)2 + 2 HCl -> CaCl2 + 2 H2O }$

Comment: Complement to what Ajkoer states. The only known solid substance containing Hypochlorite ions is Calcium Hypochlorite. Sodium hypochlorite can not exist in the solid state. It only exists in solution. If you try to evaporate it, it gets decomposed.

Comment: can we use Bleaching powder instead of  sodium hypochlorite for covid @Maurice

Comment: @SMG, the question is where do you want to use it?

Comment: yes  for this only can i do it @Maurice

Comment: for sanitation  @Maurice

Comment: @SMG, the question is where do you want to use it?

Comment: for sanitation in my housing

Comment: @SMG, Please be more specific. Housing can include everything. Very dilute bleach is only safe in the laundry and washrooms and sometimes mopping the floor, if the floors are compatible. There is no other use. Do not spray, do not use on any other stuff and avoid skin and eye contact.

Comment: You may use calcium hypochlorite for use indoors. It does not make any difference whether you use sodium or calcium hypochlorite. The only advantage of sodium salt is the fact that sodium hypochlorite can be easily washed away with plenty of water. Calcium hypochlorite contains always some chalk that is not soluble in water. This will let white spots on the surfaces after washing. On the other hand, calcium hypochlorite is more concentrated as it is solid. You will need a smaller volume of calcium hypochlorite, with respect to bleach.